# Is it possible through Facebook JS API and a Facebook Dialog to post images to my feed/wall?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I already looked into lots of articles and still have no idea how to achieve this.

I want to popup a Facebook Dialog to the user, where he will see the image he wants to share. The picture will be dynamically generated and it will not be persisted, so I don't have a permalink to the image.

So, is there any way to send binary data (the picture) to FB.ui?

Comment: this may help you: https://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-photo-upload-with-formdata/

Comment: there is no way to use binary data in FB.ui though, you would have to use static open graph tags in  the shared url for that.